# Lightbox only show's first image

Tags: javascript, html, css, featherlight.js

I'm currently working on a website with a lightbox. ([Featherlight](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/))

Now the problem is, the lightbox only load's the first image, even when I click on another image, it still show's the first.

[You can try it yourself over here](http://hugotroost.nl/jeff)

The code I used is

```
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <?php if($page->numChildren(true)) {
        echo "<ul class='project'>";
        foreach($page->children as $child) {

            if ($child->head_image) {
                $image = $child->head_image;  
                echo "<li class='item'><a href='#' data-featherlight='#mylightbox'><img id='mylightbox' src='{$image->url}' class='image'></a><p class='worktitle'>$child->title</p></li>"; 
                                }}  

                echo "</ul>";}
        ?>
    </div>
```

The site runs on ProcessWire, I made a setup like this

- Home
- Schilderingen

  - Work 1 (Here just one work, with the information)
  - Work 2 (etc)
  - Work 3
- Tekeningen

  - Work 1
  - Work 2
  - Work 3

So there is no going left or right, just that one single image that has to popup.

Does someone have any idea how to fix this, that each single image works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: all your `<img>` have the same id `mylightbox`. A solution would be to concatenate a counter or so to the `id` names, so the images and the `data-featherlight` values are **unique**

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil-nanjappa its the ID's indeed. Its solved now. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Now the next thing pops up. I have to add the captions which is given in the backend. I saw a lot of posts saying to do it with the alt attribute. [link]https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/wiki/Gallery:-showing-a-caption But it won't work because I have to get it from my backend php. Do you have any idea? I tried it this way `alt='<p class='worktitle'>$child->title</p><p class='omschrijving'>$child->image_description</p><p class='formaat'>$child->formaat</p>`'

Comment: `alt` is an attribute, I am not sure whether you can use it like `alt='<p class='worktitle' ...`. Use it like `<p alt="some string value">`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how exactly Featherlight library works, but it is probably connected with HTML IDs. You can have each id used only once, but you duplicate id "mylightbox" for every image in foreach.

Try to change the foreach to something like this:

```
foreach($page->children as $childIndex => $child) {
  if ($child->head_image) {
    $image = $child->head_image;  
    echo "<li class='item'><a href='#' data-featherlight='#mylightbox" . $childIndex . "'><img id='mylightbox" . $childIndex . "' src='{$image->url}' class='image'></a><p class='worktitle'>$child->title</p></li>"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Its indeed the ID's, as @Nikhil Nanjappa also said!