# Lightbox shows always same title

Tags: php, lightbox, featherlight.js

I asked a bit similar question last week. You can see here [Lightbox only show's first image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718492/lightbox-only-shows-first-image)

Now it only show's the one single title of the images in the lightbox of all the images. I guess its kind of the same thing but I can't figure it out. It uses the description given from the last image.

[See it over here](http://jeffreybrok.nl/schilderijen/)

Here is my code

```
<?php include("./header.inc"); ?> 
<div id="container">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <?php if($page->numChildren(true)) {
            echo "<ul class='project'>";
            foreach($page->children as $childIndex => $child)  {
                if ($child->head_image) {
                    $image = $child->head_image;  
                    echo "<li class='item'><a href='#' data-featherlight='#mylightbox" . $childIndex . "'><img id='mylightbox" . $childIndex . "' src='{$image->url}' class='image'></a></li>"; 
                    }
                }  
        echo "</ul>";}
    ?>

<style>.featherlight-content:after {
        content:"<?php echo nl2br($child->title); ?> <?php echo nl2br($child->image_description); ?> <?php echo $child->formaat; ?>";}
                        </style>                

    </div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/site/templates/scripts/lightbox/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I think its about the $childIndex which I also putted out for my previous question but I can't get it solved.

In the  tags is the text that have to be echo'd

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!!

Cheers

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for your reaction. The page is built up like this Home > schilderijen > the works. It has to popup like it does, and it works with the childIndex how Nikhil Nanjappa recommended me in the other topic. How can I use it than as an identifier?

Comment: Because what you output in `style` block is what you get after the last iteration.

Comment: So, you have to find another way to add this captions, not with `:after` style.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for your reaction. Dangit :p, I finaly got it trough this way. Is there another option how to get it without the :after?

Comment: Hmm I think @u_mulder is onto something there. I thought the caption was built from a `title` attribute but I'm not seeing that here... then again this appears to be a newer version of `lightbox`. (Removing previous comments because irrelevant, array is not associative)

Answer (score 1):

Dudes,

The problem is that the  tag that stores the information about the title is out of the loop.

To solve the problem, I'd say it is necessary to change all the code structure. For example, use static html in a echo inner the loop.